# Checar status da Internet em API 29 (Anroid Q)

Tags: android, deprecated

Boa tarde, eu possuo o seguinte método pra checar se a rede internet está ativa naquele momento:

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvaliable(Context ctx) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected());
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Mas `NetworkInfo` assim como `.getActiveNetworkInfo()` foram descontinuados na API 29. Alguém sabe de alguma solução síncrona para a API 29?

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static boolean hasInternetConnection(Context context) {

    /*
    Taken from Johan's answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35009615
     */

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    Network network;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        network = connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork();
    } else
        return true;
    NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network);
    return capabilities != null && capabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED);
}
```

fonte: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.net.ConnectivityManager&method=getNetworkCapabilities

Comment: Muito obrigado Luis, fiz algumas alterações pra minha situação, mas funcionou mto bem.